# Are there any native methods that composes valid path names and file names

Tags: c#, path, io

I wonder are there any native methods that composes valid path names and files names in C# 5 ?

I suppose it is possible with regex and such string operations manually but i wonder any native support. I mean like

```
Path.ComposeValidPath(string Path)
```

Comment: Could you give some inputs desired outcomes? you may also want to consider `Path.GetFullPath`

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Well it could be something like replacing invalid characters in a path with a certain new character. I will check Path.GetFullPath . But my aim here is composing new paths with like Path.Combine

Comment: Check [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)

Comment: `it could be something like replacing invalid characters in a path with a certain new character.` - what new character? I think this kind of path manipulation you have to do on your own. `Path` API follows one conventions regarding path validity.

Comment: You could replace all characters within `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` with an underline. I do not know of any better way to remove invalid path chars (doesn't mean much, though)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to want a function that both fixes invalid paths, and combines paths. There is already a function to combine paths. You want a function to fix invalid paths.